# Compilation error on creating a client in C

Tags: c, struct

This is my function that creates a client

```
void registerCalledOnClient(char* ip, struct sockaddr_in& remoteServer, int remotePort){

    int success, sockfd; 
    if((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) <0){
        perror("Client socket failed: ");
        exit(11);
    }
    remoteServer.sin_family = AF_INET;
    remoteServer.sin_port = htons(remotePort);
    remoteServer.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip);

    if((success = connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&remoteServer, sizeof(sockaddr_in))) < 0){
        perror("client connection failed: ")
        exit(12);
    }

}
```

This is the header signature

```
void registerCalledOnClient(char* ip, struct sockaddr_in, int remotePort);
```

And this is how I'm calling it based on user input

```
outgoingIp = strtok(NULL, " ");
remotePort = atoi(strtok(NULL, " "));
struct sockaddr_in remoteServer;

registerCalledOnClient(outgoingIp, remoteServer, remotePort);
```

This is the error I get, which I can't seem to figure out

```
    src/utilities.c:83:57: error: expected ')'
    void registerCalledOnClient(char* ip, struct sockaddr_in& remoteServer, int remotePort){
                                                            ^
    src/utilities.c:83:28: note: to match this '('
    void registerCalledOnClient(char* ip, struct sockaddr_in& remoteServer, int remotePort){
                               ^
    src/utilities.c:83:57: error: parameter name omitted
    void registerCalledOnClient(char* ip, struct sockaddr_in& remoteServer, int remotePort){

src/utilities.c:90:2: error: use of undeclared identifier 'remoteServer'
        remoteServer.sin_family = AF_INET;
        ^
src/utilities.c:91:2: error: use of undeclared identifier 'remoteServer'
        remoteServer.sin_port = htons(remotePort);
        ^
src/utilities.c:91:32: error: use of undeclared identifier 'remotePort'
        remoteServer.sin_port = htons(remotePort);
```

I'm not very fluent with C. Any help appreciated.

Comment: That's vile c++ heresy!

Comment: What's the `&` doing in the first line? That's C++ (reference) syntax, I believe.

Comment: Could someone modify the registerCalledOnClient function and explain how exactly I could pass a pointer to the struct. Also what should be the method signature in this case and how can I call it.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
struct sockaddr_in& remoteServer
```

is not C syntax, that looks like C++ where the `&` symbol is used like that to declare a reference. C doesn't have references; you have to pass the structure by value or use a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

C does not have C++ reference types  you cannot have a `struct sockaddr_in&`.  Pass a pointer or by copy, or use C++ compilation.

Comment: Can you please modify the client function to explain how I can pass a pointer to this struct. Also what should be the method signature in this case and how do I call it.

Comment: @antithesis : That is not within the scope of your question, and is easily answered by any C programming reference.

Answer (score 0):

Your function prototype is not valid C.  You appear to be using C++'s pass-by-reference syntax for remoteServer, which is confusing your C compiler.  Try passing it by value or by pointer instead.